# QNEAT3 Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I'm using the GUI for QGIS (not writing my own Python script). I'm new to QGIS.

I'm using the QNEAT3 plugin to create isochrones using the Iso-Area as Polygons (from Point) algorithm. I'm getting the following error when I run the algorithm (screenshot of my parameters is below for reference):

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users/emmaj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromPoint.py",
> line 249, in processAlgorithm polygon_featurelist =
> net.calcIsoPolygons(max_dist, interval, output_path) File
> "C:\Users/emmaj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py",
> line 470, in calcIsoPolygons band_in = ds_in.GetRasterBand(1)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

The parameters attached are what I'm using right now, but I will need to change the size of Iso-area eventually to create different isochrones. However, I've replicated this error with different size values.

[image]

Comment: This error is usually related to bad connectivity in the graph file (do the edges/lines of the graph connect with eachother?). If the algorithm cant route through edges, no cost raster can be interpolated, hence the error. You can check if you have a connectivity issue by running the Iso-Pointcloud algorithm and see if you get a meaningful output there.